# UITextView not printing multiple lines

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm just reading from a database and I want to output a couple rows.

I have the following code:

```
 for row in try inventoryDB.prepare("SELECT name, amount FROM inventory") {
       textView1.text = ("name: \(row[0]), amount: \(row[1])")
       //textView1.text=("test \n")
       // id: Optional(2), email: Optional("betty@icloud.com")
       // id: Optional(3), email: Optional("cathy@icloud.com")
 }
```

and that just prints the top line.

Changing it to

```
 print("name: \(row[0]), amount: \(row[1])")
```

displays all the data, line by line in the console, so I know it's there.

I've tried appending line breaks, `\n`, into the `UITextViewcall`, but it still only prints the topmost line.

Am I just formatting something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the contents of the text View for each row of the DB and so you end up with the last row value in the text view once you are done. You can get all the content first into a string and finally display it in the text view, as follows:

```
var txt = ""
for row in try inventoryDB.prepare("SELECT name, amount FROM inventory") {
       txt  += "name: \(row[0]), amount: \(row[1])\n" 
       //textView1.text=("test \n")
       // id: Optional(2), email: Optional("betty@icloud.com")
       // id: Optional(3), email: Optional("cathy@icloud.com")
}
textView1.text = txt
```

Comment: Ahhh! I see now. I tried that += to the textView earlier but it told me I couldn't -- I didn't try it with an existing string. I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

You replace the value of `textView1` for every row. I would map your data to an array of string. Then, you can join each element with a linebreak.

```
let text = try inventoryDB.prepare("SELECT name, amount FROM inventory").map({ row -> String in
       return "name: \(row[0]), amount: \(row[1])"
 }).joined(separator: "\n")
textView1.text = text
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing the text of the TextView inside a loop, you are not appending the strings that you are getting from the loop.

Try this:

```
var alltext = ""
for row in try inventoryDB.prepare("SELECT name, amount FROM inventory"){
alltext = alltext + "name: \(row[0]), amount: \(row[1]) \n"
}
textView1.text = alltext
```

Be sure that your textView is formatted to show more than 1 line too.

Answer (score -1):

In swift 3.0, this worked for me:

```
print("name: \(row[0]), amount: \(row[1])", terminator: "\n")
```